# The ...works best with java script enabled message hides the search input box

Tags: feature-request, status-declined

I'm using Chrome Plus and most of the time the "Stack Overflow works best with JavaScript enabled" message hides the search entry. It would be nice if those menu entries would stay visible on the page

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't understand this request. Why do you have JavaScript disabled? Fix that, first.

edit: I believe this is a bug in ChromePlus, not us.

Comment: It seems to be a ChromePlus issue. The disable JavaScript Checkbox isn't checked. And I tried Firefox where all is fine.

Comment: @bern I remember a very old Chrome beta had this bug, where it would render `<noscript>` blocks inappropriately.. you might consider that.

Comment: Accepted, I just switch to Firefox

Comment: Finally I found the cause of the problem.
In Chrome Plus I use the extension FastestChrome - Browse Faster - Version: 3.1.4

The problem occurs, when the option Enable Endless Pages is checked.