# Why is superuser.com telling me that it works better with JavaScript enabled?

Tags: support, stack-overflow, javascript

I am very sure this is a website question now. I'm on Google Chrome, and JavaScript is most definitely enabled. There are no exceptions in the settings. I'm running on Ubuntu Linux, with the [GNOME](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNOME) desktop currently. Everything is as current as Ubuntu tells it to be.

Comment: Is it only Super User or are the other size affected as well? Have you tried clearing your cache and/or force reloading the page?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I had a similar problem

[link](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/72323/the-works-best-with-java-script-enabled-message-hides-the-search-input-box)

Finally I found the cause of the problem. In Chrome Plus I use the extension FastestChrome - Browse Faster - Version: 3.1.4 The problem occurs, when the option Enable Endless Pages is checked.

Comment: Oh man, thats amazing. i didnt even think about that. thank you. id vote this up, but im not allowed.